# How to give each button a different value from an array with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array of movie genres and the idea is to always take a random value from the array and add it to 4 HTML buttons that server as answers for a quiz question. I managed to randomize the values I take from the array, however, that value gets repeated for all 4 buttons. What I want is that each button takes a different value from the array and to be it random at the same time.

```
const genres = ["Crime", "Action", "Drama", "Thriller", "Horror", "Comedy", "History", "Romance", "Adventure", "Epic", "Sci-Fi" ];
const randGenres = Math.floor(Math.random()*genres.length);

let answers = document.querySelectorAll('.answer');
[].forEach.call(answers, function(answers){
    answers.innerHTML = movies[randAnswer] && genres[randGenres];
});
```

```
      <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
      <div class="question">

      </div>
      <button class="answer">Some Answer</button>
      <button class="answer">Some Answer</button>   
      <button class="answer">Some Answer</button>
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the random number in the loop, if you define it before the loop it will always stay the same

```
forEach.call(answers, function(answers){
    randGenres = Math.floor(Math.random()*genres.length);
    answers.innerHTML = movies[randAnswer] && genres[randGenres];
});
```